Stylelint Error: "Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element" When Using SCSS Mixins to Generate CSS Variables
I'm encountering an issue with Stylelint when using SCSS mixins to generate CSS variables. The error message I receive is:
    Error: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.
        at /path/to/project/src/styles/mixins/_generate-css-variables.scss:8:53
        at Root._error (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:130:16)
        at Root.error (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/selectors/root.js:30:19)
        at Parser.error (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:596:21)
        at Parser.expected (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:922:19)
        at Parser.pseudo (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:728:19)
        at Parser.parse (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:884:14)
        at Parser.loop (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:853:12)
        at new Parser (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:123:10)
        at Processor._root (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/processor.js:40:18)
        at Processor._runSync (/path/to/project/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/processor.js:78:21)

SCSS Mixin:
I have a mixin that generates CSS variables from a palette. Here's a simplified version of the mixin:
    @mixin generate-css-variables($palette, $palette-name) {
      @each $key, $value in $palette {
        @if $key == 'contrast' {
          @each $contrast-key, $contrast-value in $value {
            --#{$palette-name}-contrast-#{$contrast-key}: #{$contrast-value};
          }
        } @else {
          --#{$palette-name}-#{$key}: #{$value};
        }
      }
    }

Usage Example:
The mixin is used in another scss file like this:
    @import 'mixins/generate-css-variables';
    
    $colors: (
      primary: #ff0000,
      secondary: #00ff00,
      contrast: (
        light: #ffffff,
        dark: #000000
      )
    );
    
    :root {
      @include generate-css-variables($colors, 'color');
    }

Stylelint Configuration:
Here are parts of my current Stylelint configuration:

    {
      "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
      "plugins": ["stylelint-scss"],
      "rules": {
        "selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown": [
          true,
          {
            "ignorePseudoClasses": ["host"]
          }
        ],
        "no-invalid-double-slash-comments": null,
        "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": [
          true,
          {
            "ignorePseudoElements": ["ng-deep"]
          }
        ],
        "no-invalid-position-at-import-rule": null,
        "at-rule-no-unknown": null,
        "max-nesting-depth": [
          5,
          {
            "ignoreAtRules": ["include"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

Question:
How can I modify my Stylelint configuration to avoid the "Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element" error without changing the SCSS code? Is there a specific rule I can add to ignore this error for generated CSS variables?
Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
